# Send multiple mails with different subject and message using WordPress wp_mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress + a contact form that sends emails with the **wp_mail** function. What i need now is that it automatically sends two (or more) emails with DIFFERENT subjects and messages.

1. to me
2. to the visitor – individually adapted to his inputs
3. to *nozbe.com* which converts mails into tasks (hastags in subject)
4. and maybe more in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the sending of an email from wordpress, check if the email to send is from your contact form and finally perform your custom actions (sending the 2 emails).

You could do this by registering a filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail' );
function my_wp_mail($attributes)
{
    //If the subject matches the subject from the contact form do the following:
       //Change the subject (so that this code gets only performed once, and not EVERY time the wp_mail function is called)
       //Send your custom mails by calling the wp_mail function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/
       //You can access the attributes by calling $attributes['subject'], $attributes['message'], $attributes['to'], ...
    return $attributes;
}
```

So the only thing you need to edit in your example is to remove the key `_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted-0` once you performed your custom action (so they don't get performed infinite times).

Comment: Once again just a small thing, why it did not work .. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### THE SOLUTION

```
function my_wp_mail_func( $args ) {

    // checks data origin (in this case contact module of Divi theme)
    if ( array_key_exists('et_pb_contactform_submit_0', $_POST) ){

        // prevents infinite loop
        unset($_POST["et_pb_contactform_submit_0"]);

        $message = $args['message'] . ' 2';
        $subject = $args["subject"] . ' 2';
        $to = "recipient2@domain.com";

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $args['headers'], $args['attachments'] );

        $message = $args['message'] . ' 3';
        $subject = $args["subject"] . ' 3';
        $to = "recipient3@domain.com";

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $args['headers'], $args['attachments'] );

        return $args;
    }

    return $args;

}

add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail_func' );
```